# how to input multiple data types in c

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I'm trying to write a program calculates based on keyboard input like a b c, a is number 1, b is number2 and c is operator but it's doesn't allow me to assign b when I use string, it doesn't show c when I use char can someone explain how this work please and how can I input multiple data types I'm new to C and i tried C++ before it's easier to input them

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
int a , b;
char c[1];
scanf("%i%i%s", &a, &b, &c); //type 2 3 +

printf("%i %i %s",a,b,c);

}
```

the output is 2 0 +

and when i tried to use char
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
int a , b;
char c;
scanf("%i%i%c", &a, &b, &c);

printf("%i %i %c",a,b,c);

}
```

the output is 2 3 it's not showing c nor recognise it

Comment: Have you read about what `scanf` returns? If you expect it to extract three values, you should also check that it returns `3`. If it does not, you haven't gotten three values from the user.

Comment: `char c[1];` isn't large enough to hold a 1 character string and properly terminate it. You need at least 2 characters of space. Speaking of space, it is a character too. Change your printf to `printf("%i %i '%c'",a,b,c);` and see what happens. Read through [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer) and consider changing the scanf format string to `"%i%i %c"`.

Comment: `%s` with a `char[1]` allows for exactly zero characters entered + the null terminator. If you use `scanf` to read into `char` arrays, subtract one from the array length and limit the `scanf`: For `char c[10]` it'd be `scanf("%9s", c);` - see the error?

Comment: You might be interested in https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: You should check the value returned by `scanf()`.  If it isn't 3, something has gone wrong.  The second code fragment would work if you typed `2 3+`, but  you need to add a space before `%c` in the `scanf()` format `"%i%i%c"` for it to accept `2 3 +`.  That's because `%c` is one of the three conversion specifiers that does not skip white space (the other two are `%[…]` scan sets and `%n`).  (More precisely, when you enter `2 3 +` with the `"%i%i%c"` format, the space after `3` is put into variable `c`.)  Don't forget to end your `printf()` messages with a newline.

Comment: You got a couple of answers below.  Please accept the best one by clicking the check mark next to it so we know you are all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `char c[2]` is needed hold a string with one character with the terminating `'\0'`.

   You could also use `char c[1]` or just `char c` and read a single non-space character with  `%c` (space prefix is significant).  When you print the character you then need to use the `%c` (instead of `%s`) conversion specifier.
2. Always use a maximum field width when reading a string with `scanf()` to avoid buffer overflow.
3. The format string `%s` requires a matching `char *` which you write as just `c`.
4. On success `scanf()` return the number of items successfully matched.  If you don't check for that you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
5. (Not fixed) If you only enter two numbers, `scanf()` will be waiting for the operator.  If you don't want this behavior use `fgets()` or `getline()` to get a line of input.  Then process that that with `sscanf()` or lower level functions like `strtol()`.  This ensures you make progress by selecting what you need and discarding everything else.  Separating I/O handling (checking for `EOF`) and parsing also leads to simpler code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[2];
    if(scanf("%i%i%1s", &a, &b, c) != 3) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    };
    printf("%i %i %s\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Example run:

```
$ ./a.out
1 x
scanf failed
$ ./a.out
1 2 +
1 2 +
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem1: If you declare a string, it has a `'\0'` at the end, so you need increase array length, like `c[2]`. So it will be

```
[0] [1]
 +  '\0'
```

Problem 2: When input `2 3 +`, `c` will get a space after `3`, so you need to type `2 3+` to get `+`.